# Running firefox inside vagrant machine

Tags: firefox, vagrant

I wish to run a firefox with complete gui inside a vagrant machine to test one of my application installed in it.

From my host machine I issued following command to get inside the vagrant

```
$ vagrant ssh
$ sudo su -
```

Now when I am trying to run firefox using following command it is throwing an error:

```
$ firefox
Error: no display specified
```

Although I have tested the web application using 'lynx' tool but I want to test it with complete gui.

Please let me know if there is any possible solution for this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have an X server on the host:

```
$ vagrant ssh -- -X
$ firefox  # or sudo firefox, if you must
```